# Remove newlines in file names

Tags: files, scripting, rename

I have a PHP code that generates the file name on which wget will append its logs. I generated 2000+ files, but the problem is I am having trouble working with them because I had a mistake of putting `PHP_EOL` as part of its name, that code will add
`LF/line feed/%0A` at its name

Example of such file name (when accessed via browser, when put on /var/www/html) `http://xxxx/wget_01_a%0a.txt` notice the `%0a` before the extension name

I messed up, and I wish there's a rename batch that will search through all files and if it found `line feed` it would rename it without the line feed so it would just be `http://xxxx/wget_01_a.txt`

I am not pretty sure how to handle this because seems like when I `ls` on putty all special character not limited to that unwanted char becomes `?`, what I only wish to target is that line feed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using the utility `rename` from util-linux, which CentOS 6 provides, and assuming bash:

```
rename $'\n' '' wget_*
```

This asks to delete newline characters from the names of listed files. I recommend trying it out on a small subset to ensure it does what you want it to (note that `rename` on CentOS 7 supports a `-v` switch to show you what changes it is making).

If instead you were on a distribution that provides the Perl-based `rename`:

```
rename -n 's/\n//g' wget_*
```

And then run without `-n` to actually perform the renaming.

Comment: bro, nothing happened http://pastebin.com/NjMg8vTL I am using centos 6

Comment: Perhaps the linefeed character you have isn't actually `\n`? Can you do something like echo `*.txt | od -c` so we see what actual non-printable character is there?

Comment: seems like `\n` http://pastebin.com/wXCDCJjr

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong, unless for some reason the file in your previous paste does not match `*.txt` (which would explain why `rename` doesn't pick it up). If you set the two patterns to, say, `txt` instead of `$'\n'` and `''`, do you get any output? Does echo $'\n' indeed print two newlines?

Comment: removing `-v` to parameter seemed to solved my problem? if you update your answer I can mark your answer correct thanks!

Comment: Well, that's weird; this must mean your version of `rename` does not support options and understood your query to mean "replace `-v` with newline". It's great if it means your problem is solved. Out of curiosity, what does `rename --help` say about `-v`, if anything?

Comment: Oh I see; CentOS 6 `rename` only supports `call: rename from to files...`. I will edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21916/discussion-between-dhag-and-the-wolf).

Comment: I had to use `rename $'\r' '' wget_*` for it to work

Answer (score 6):

Building on what was already answered, I've generalized it to rename all files containing line feed in current folder and sub-folder, by combining find command with rename -

```
find -name $'*\n*' -exec rename  $'s|\n| |g' '{}' \;
```

Here, find command locates all files containing line feed and rename command replaces every line feed in the name with a space.

The same can be done for any other such problematic characters such as carriage return (\r).

Comment: This worked for me, unlike the accepted answer.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04