# Recursively remove newline in file names

Tags: rename, newlines

Just as the title suggests, I want to scan a directory and all the subdirectories and remove all newline characters from the filenames.

The current solution proposed here is not working: [Remove newlines in file names](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/397659/373183)

This is what I got when I used it:

```
$ find -name $'*\n*' -exec rename $'s|\n| |g' '{}' \; 
rename: not enough arguments 
Try 'rename --help' for more information.
```

if I add a `*`

```
$ find -name $'*\n*' -exec rename $'s|\n| |g' '{}' * \;
```

this does not produce any error messages (just accepts the command) but it does not rename the file in the subdirectory

Comment: In which way your cited answer isn't working? Can you add some console output of it?

Comment: Are you sure it's newline `\n` you want to remove? Apparently, in the question you linked to, the relevant characted was "carriage return" `\r` instead. Maybe that's what you need too?

Comment: Please edit your question and put additional details there.

Comment: Based on the error message, it looks like `rename` on your system is the `util-linux` implementation (whereas the linked answer assumes one of the Perl-based implementations). What type or flavor of Unix / Linux are you using?

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver, I am using the latest Manjaro KDE. I was not aware there is a difference. When I run `$ rename --version`

I get `rename from util-linux 2.34`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage of the `rename` command provided by `util-linux` is different from that given in the answer you linked. In particular, it requires a separate `from` and `to` argument rather than a single sed-style replacement command - hence the error message `not enough arguments`.

```
SYNOPSIS
       rename [options] expression replacement file...
```

So in this case you would need

```
find . -name $'*\n*' -exec rename $'\n' ' ' {} \;
```

See also:

- [Why is the rename utility on Debian/Ubuntu different than the one on other distributions, like CentOS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275254/why-is-the-rename-utility-on-debian-ubuntu-different-than-the-one-on-other-distr)
- [What's with all the renames: prename, rename, file-rename?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229230/whats-with-all-the-renames-prename-rename-file-rename)

and for a simple usage comparison

- [Find all [filename].mp4 and rename [filename].audio](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/238862/65304)

Comment: But that (very limited) `rename` implementation only replaces once occurrence per filename.

Comment: You'd also want `-depth` or it wouldn't properly if there were directories with newlines in their path.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you use one of the `perl`-based `rename` variants, sometimes called `prename`, not the one from `util-linux` (sometimes called `rename.ul`).

The one from `util-linux` is much more limited (despite being much newer), uses a different syntax, can only replace fixed strings and can't replace all the occurrences of a string.

Here, I'd use perl `rename` variants, make sure to only convert newlines in the file names, not the directory components leading to them, and use `-depth` to process leaves before branches.

`perl` recognises `\n` as meaning a newline, so you don't need to use `$'...'` for its code argument (though it's fine if you do contrary to what I initially thought).

```
find . -depth -name $'*\n*' -exec rename '
  s{[^/]*\z}{$& =~ y/\n/ /r}e' '{}' +
```

Or use `-execdir` if available (though that will run at least one `rename` per directory with files with `\n` within):

```
find . -depth -name $'*\n*' -execdir rename 'y/\n/ /' {} +
```

Or you could use `zsh`'s `zmv`:

```
autoload zmv
NL=$'\n'
zmv "(**/)(*$NL*)(#qD)" '$1${2//$NL/ }'
```

(which contrary to the `find`-based approaches will still work even if file names contain sequences of bytes that don't  form valid characters. It will also bail out without doing anything if it detects a conflict).