# can't stat a file with newline in name

Tags: files

I have a file with the following name (I didn't name it!):

`'A MULTI BAND MINI PRINTED OMNI DIRECTIONAL'$'\n''ANTENNA WITH V-SHAPED FOR RFID APPLICATIONS.pdf'`

Weirdness is caused by the '$'\n' in the middle of the filename.

I can't do anything with this file except show it in `ls`!.

How do I remove or rename this file?

I've looked at other [answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/542445/307402) on this site and tried the solutions provided - they all seem to have absolutely no effect.  ls -l shows the following permissions for the file:

`-rwxrwxrwx`

Comment: Assuming the quotes are not part of the file name, I created a file with this name as follows: `touch 'A MULTI BAND MINI PRINTED OMNI DIRECTIONAL'\$'\n''ANTENNA WITH V-SHAPED FOR RFID APPLICATIONS.pdf'`. A directory listing shows `-rw-rw-r-- 1 bbausch bbausch 0 May  6 14:38 A MULTI BAND MINI PRINTED OMNI DIRECTIONAL$\nANTENNA WITH V-SHAPED FOR RFID APPLICATIONS.pdf
`. To delete it, I then typed `rm A` followed by a tab; the filename was expanded, and the `rm` command succeeded.

Comment: I also created a file with the quotes in the name. To remove that, `rm "'"*` (hoping no other filename starts with a quote).

Comment: What shell are you using? What did you try to remove or rename the file?

Comment: If you have a modern Linux system (Ubuntu 18.04 is modern enough, 16.04 isn't), the default output of `ls` is exactly what you need to type in your shell.

Comment: @berndbausch:  I should have mentioned that the obvious solution, `rm A <Tab Completion>` doesn't work.  It simply won't expand the filename.  Once I type "A", it won't auto-complete.  If I type `A\ M`, tab completion ERASES the '\ M' and leaves the A!  I don't get it.

Comment: @berndbausch, no the quotes are not part of the filename.  that's just how it's shown in the output of `ls`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas:  I'm using bash, but could use something else if it will work.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil':  If I take the output of ls, highlight it, and paste it into `ls <filename>` or `rm <filename>`, the response is "No such file or directory.

Comment: My guess is that there are non-printable characters in the filename. I am not sure if `ls` has an option to show them; if all else fails, you could pipe `ls` output into `cat -v` or `od -c`, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User beware:  The problem here was that file I was working with was on a network file system mounted via cifs.  I guess those weird filenames just don't work well over networked file systems.

The solution was to ssh into the NAS box and remove the file using `rm` in a local shell.