# recursively remove newline from directory names

Tags: bash, zsh

I have few directories whose names looks like the following:

[image]

I want to remove the newline from the end recursively.

I checked [Recursively rename directories](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/163728-recursively-rename-directories.html)

I also checked [Remove newlines in file names](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/397659)

The solution it suggests is:

```
find -name $'*\n*' -exec rename  $'s|\n| |g' '{}' \;
```

But in my case `find -name $'*\n*'` returns nothing. If I remove the `$` it can find the directories

```
% find . -name '*\n*'
./second?
% find . -name '*\r*'
./third?
./first?
```

However, when I run `find . -name '*\n*' -exec rename  $'s|\n| |g' '{}' \;` it does not rename the directory. I also tried `find . -name $'*\n*' -exec rename $'\n' ' ' {} \;` from [Recursively remove newline in file names](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/542445). It is also not renaming the directories.

What can I do?

Comment: On Linux, with GNU tools, `find -name $'*\n*'` works for me and finds filenames with hard newlines. `-name '*\n*'` is the same as `-name '*n*'` and finds names with an `n`... What shell are you actually running? You tagged this with both [tag:bash] and [tag:zsh], and they should both support `$'...'`. Are you sure it's the actual newline character you have there, and not something different? What do you get if you run `ls --quoting-style=shell-escape` (with a recent-ish GNU ls) or `printf "%q\n" *` (in Bash or Zsh) in the directory with those dirs?

Comment: I'd remove the leading `$` from both strings, i.e. `find . -depth -name '*\n*' -exec rename  's|\n|_|g' {} \;`

Comment: Also, for the commands with `rename`, you need to know if you have the Perl one, or the util-linux one... What does `rename --version` say? (see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/510583/170373 and links therein)

Comment: @ilkkachu `printf "%q\n" *` shows `first$'\342\200\251'
second$'\342\200\251'
third$'\342\200\251'`

Comment: @ilkkachu `rename --version` says `/usr/bin/rename using File::Rename version 1.10`

Comment: @blueray, ah-ha. Well, that's not the regular newline then, but something completely different. Thanks for the clear clarifications.

Comment: perl rename only renames a file if `$_` is changed by the rename script, so you can just use `find . -type d -exec rename 's/[\n\r]/ /g' {} +`.   directory names with newlines and/or carriage-returns in them will be renamed, directories without will be ignored.

Comment: or `find . -type d -exec rename 's/[\n\r]|\342\200\251/ /g' {} +`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said that

> `printf "%q\n" *` shows `first$'\342\200\251' second$'\342\200\251' third$'\342\200\251'`

The `$'\342\200\251'` there isn't the regular newline, it's the [Unicode U+2029 PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2029/index.htm), encoded in UTF-8. The output there has the bytes in octal; in hex, they would be `e2 80 a9`.

That's why `find -name $'*\n*'` doesn't match it. Without the dollar, `-name '*\n*'` would be the same as just `-name '*n*'` matching the letter `n` in `second`. The patterns `-name` takes are just shell glob patterns, where `\` makes the next character non-special. E.g. `\*` matches just the single asterisk, while `*` matches anything. `n` isn't special, so `\n` is just the same as it.

Given we now know what it is, we can get rid of it in the same way we would of a newline. With the Perl rename (e.g. the one using `File::Rename`), this should just remove them:

```
find . -depth -name $'*\342\200\251' \
       -execdir rename -v $'s|\342\200\251||g' '{}' +
```

You need `-depth` for leaves to be renamed before branches they're on and `-execdir` (not standard but pretty common) for `rename` to be called from within the directories containing the files to rename with only the basenames of the files.

`... rename -v 's|\342\200\251||g'` should work too, since it's a Perl expression and Perl *does* interpret backslash escapes itself, too.

The command you had, has `rename  $'s|\n| |g'` which would replace with a space, but since you have the characters at the end of the names, that would also be confusing.

Comment: thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv -v $'(**/)(*[\n\u2029]*)(#qD)' $'$1${2//[\u2029\n]}'
```

To remove both newlines (U+000A) or the *paragraph separator* character (U+2029).

Or:

```
zmv -v $'(**/)(*[[:cntrl:]]*)(#qD)' $'$1${2//[[:cntrl:]]}'
```

to remove all control characters.

Whether U+2029 will be classified as `cntrl` or not will depend on the system though. It is on Ubuntu 20.04, but not on FreeBSD 12.2 for instance. Run `[[ $'\u2029' = [[:cntrl:]] ]] && echo yes` to check on your system.

Comment: OP here. This is actually a better solution. But, as I have already accepted an answer, I do not want to change it. Moreover, @ilkkachu taught me to use `printf "%q\n" *` to find what the real control operator is so I think he deserves some appreciation.